# Add two vectors using python's operator overloading feauture

Tags: python-3.x

I want to add two vectors with n dimensions using the **add** method operator overloading . The elements of the 2 vectors will be input by the user. I don't understand how to define the vector as a single object.
In my example code vectors s1 and s2 have 2 defined values.I want the vectors to take input from the user having N dimensions and then add them using class and the **add** method.I can do it using only functions without using class and object but it is for a homework and the use of class is required.For example :

```
s1 = [float(x) for x in input().split()]
s2= [float(x) for x in input().split()]
s3=s1+s2
```

I am clueless on what to do and any help will be appreciated.

```
class Student :

def __init__(self,m1,m2) :

   self.m1=m1
   self.m2=m2

def __add__(self,other) :
   m1=self.m1+other.m1
   m2=self.m2+other.m2   
   s3=Student(m1,m2)
   return s3

s1=Student(58,69)
s2=Student(60,65)
s3=s1+s2
print(s3.m1,s3.m2)
```

Comment: The code below is for adding 2 vectors with 2 standard dimensions.I dont know how to proceed when i have add  the elements of two vectors with N dimensions.The elements will be the input of the user like the example in the first code

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use `numpy` following solution will work:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([float(x) for x in "1 2 3".split()])
y = np.array([float(x) for x in "3 4 5".split()])

print(x)
# [1. 2. 3.]
print(y)
# [3. 4. 5.]
print(x+y)
# [4. 6. 8.]

class Student:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Student(self.data+other.data)

student_x = Student(x)
student_y = Student(y)
print((student_x+student_y).data)
# [4. 6. 8.]
```